# Executing a native File from init.rc in Android

Tags: android, shell, android-source, selinux, init.d

I want to execute a file from vendor/bin from my init.rc. Below code I have added to my init.rc file

```
on property:sys.vendor.Test_callback=1
exec - system system -- /vendor/bin/testBinary
setprop sys.test.hello 62
```

The property `sys.test.hello` is added here to check if the property getting called or not. I can see that the value is updating to 62 after the execution.

The problem here is with `exec - system system -- /vendor/bin/testBinary` this is not getting executed.

When I run as root from adb shell this works fine.

Following are the permission to the file `testBinary` obtained after doing ls -l

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root      shell
```

What I am doing wrong here?
SE linux policy has been already disabled to test this.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it as service from `init.rc`.

first define service somewhere in `init.rc`

```
service testBinary /vendor/bin/testBinary 
        disabled
        oneshot
```

Somewhere in `init.rc` where you are setting `sys.vendor.Test_callback` to `1` call.

```
star testBinary
```

You can remove `oneshot` if you want to service to be restarted when it crashes.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work out. Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: No new observation, Infact in adb logs I cant see any message regarding this test binary.
Earlier I was getting some Selinux policy errors when I was executing this with 
"exec - system system -- /vendor/bin/testBinary". Later I disabled se policy

Comment: This solution is only working with user debug builds but fails with user build.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here issue was that, I was setting the property from an application which was not running in Phone process.
Solution: I created a service in com.android.phone and executed the command `exec - system system -- /vendor/bin/testBinary` from the new service and it worked for me.

PS : Answer posted by @Kiran Biradar also works fine when executed from the new service

Answer (score 0):

Try to use just

```
exec -- /vendor/bin/testBinary
```